# Talend java code was disappear and Execution failed: null exception

Tags: java, talend

My Java code of Talend job has disappeared, I m not able to run simple `printf` statement in the job. It throws the error `Execution failed: null`. When I check the logs from .metadata/.logs it shows the null pointer exception.

My job code was below:

```
String foo = "bar";
System.out.println(foo);
```

My below exception:-

```
Execution failed: null      
    Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The import org.talend.designer.codegen.config cannot be resolved
    CodeGeneratorArgument cannot be resolved to a type
    CodeGeneratorArgument cannot be resolved to a type
```

From the Error logs (.metadata/.logs):

```
    !ENTRY org.talend.platform.logging 4 0 2018-06-20 12:12:35.901
    !MESSAGE 2018-06-20 12:12:35,900 ERROR org.talend.commons.exception.CommonExceptionHandler  -  !STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.jet.JETEmitter.generate(JETEmitter.java:467)
    at org.talend.designer.codegen.config.TalendJetEmitter.generate(TalendJetEmitter.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.jet.JETEmitter.generate(JETEmitter.java:447)
    at org.eclipse.emf.codegen.jet.JETEmitter.generate(JETEmitter.java:438)
    at org.talend.designer.codegen.proxy.JetProxy.generate(JetProxy.java:54)
    at org.talend.designer.codegen.CodeGenerator.generateContextCode(CodeGenerator.java:434)
    at org.talend.designer.core.runprocess.Processor.updateContextCode(Processor.java:625)
    at org.talend.designer.runprocess.java.JavaProcessor.generateContextCode(JavaProcessor.java:1254)
    at org.talend.designer.runprocess.ProcessorUtilities.generateContextInfo(ProcessorUtilities.java:560)
    at org.talend.designer.runprocess.ProcessorUtilities.generateCode(ProcessorUtilities.java:406)
    at org.talend.designer.runprocess.ProcessorUtilities.generateCode(ProcessorUtilities.java:1095)
    at org.talend.designer.runprocess.RunProcessContext$1.run(RunProcessContext.java:487)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:464
```

if I receive the solution without deleting the workspace or uninstall/ reinstall the talend it will be great.

Comment: Can you give some more details of where you are getting the message, and perhaps a screen grab if the job as it’s hard to see where your problem might be. Also state which version, platform and java jre as that helps.

Comment: I was getting this error message(Execution failed: null ) when I executing the job .  But the job doesn't have an option to create the null exception, and I have mentioned above my error logs (C:\Talend\5.3.1\cmdline\studio\workspace\.metadata)


I have using talend 5.3.1 and Java 1.7.0_79

Comment: I have this below exception which looks like java or talend issue not from the job.                                                                                                   
     
 !MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Failed to execute runnable (java.lang.NullPointerException)
 at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4083)
 at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:3998)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:137)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4041)

Comment: Hello, did you solve your problem ? If not, could you please try the following ?
1.Close your Talend studio 2.Delete .Java, .JETEmitters and .metadata folders from your workspace. 3. Restart your studio

Comment: I have found some suggestions in community forums as you send me but is there any suggestion is possible without deleting those things.

Comment: I faced similar problem (null pointer exception) when I installed Java and Talend on my new computer. I could not run a simple job. The code section was completely Blank. Then, I changed my computer language to the English. The problem was solved. Check your language of the computer.